# Why does implicit coercion for addition always produce a string?

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence, coercion

If only the second operand in addition is a string then the output is a string:

```
let a = 1 + '2';
console.log(typeof a);  // string
```

And if, instead, only the first operand is a string, then the output is still a string:

```
let b = '1' + 2;
console.log(typeof b);  // string
```

I was guessing that there would be some kind of argument precedence. Is there a reason why this mathematical function defaults to a non-numerical output with mixed-type arguments?

Comment: That's just the way the language was designed.

Comment: This is part of the ECMAScript specification, so basically it's part of the language. [Here's the relevant section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation) (specifically item 11) if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks @CRice. I had a wee look. Yes, that is some light reading ;)

Comment: All the binary operations work this way. When coercing the arguments to the same type, order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a single operator is part of an expression, the expression is performed left to right, but in JavaScript, if any one of the operands used with the `+` operator is a string, the other one will be converted to a string - it doesn't matter which one. This is because the `+` operation can mean string addition (concatenation) or mathematical addition. When one operand is a string, the JavaScript runtime correctly assumes that the `+` should mean string addition because the string could contain a non-numeric value and doing math with non-numeric values is problematic, to say the least.

You would need to do a conversion on the non-string before the concatenation occurs. This can be done in a number of ways:

```js
console.log(1 + +"2");              // prepending a + to a string attempts to convert to a number

// Note that with all of the following there is a nested function call being performed
// and these functions take an argument, which requires () for the argument to be passed.
// Because of the nested (), that function call is performed first and the result of the 
// function call is returned to the expression.

console.log(1 + parseInt("2.4"));   // parse the integer portion of the string into a number
console.log(1 + parseFloat("2.4")); // parse the floating point number in the string into a number
console.log(1 + Number("2"));       // convert the string into a number
```

The basic operator precedence is:

- Parenthesis
- Exponents
- Multiplication
- Division
- Addition
- Subtraction

So, in the following examples, you can see that happening:

```js
// Here, the order of operations will be:

  // Parenthesis:    (2/2) === 1
  // Multiplication: 10 * 1 === 10
  // Addition:       1 + 10 === 11
  // Subtraction:    11 - 3 === 8
console.log(1 + 10 * (2 / 2) - 3);

// But here, because of the string, the order of operations will be:

  // Parenthesis:    (2/2) === 1
  // Multiplication: 10 * 1 === 10
  // Addition:       "1" + 10 === "110" (one operand is a string, so the other converts to a string)
  // Subtraction:    "110" - 3 === 107  (the string "110" will be implicitly converted to a number
  //                                     becuase the - sign  only has one meaning in a mathmatical 
  //                                     expression)
console.log("1" + 10 * (2 / 2) - 3);
```

See **[JavaScript Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)** for a full list of operators and their precedence.

See **[Unary `+` Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)** for how it is used to convert to a number.

Also note that we're not talking about "arguments" here (an argument is what is passed to a method or function). These are ***operands*** in an expression with ***operators***.

Comment: So there is no argument precedence in JS?

Comment: @cham There is ***operator*** precedence and I've provided a link for that, but the ***operands*** themselves don't have any particular precedence. As I mentioned in my "Note", we're not talking about arguments here.

Answer (score 2):

As it is often the case, the answer is "because the spec says so". More specifically, [section 11.6.1 The Addition operator ( + )](https://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1).

On step 7, you can read

> If Type(*lprim*) is String or Type(*rprim*) is String, then
>        Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(*lprim*) followed by ToString(*rprim*)

In other words, if at least one of the operands is a string, the result will be the concatenation of the string representation of both operands.

There is precedence in a way, because if both operands were functions the left one would be evaluated before the right one, but it doesn't matter for the algorithm that decides if the `+` operation should return a string or a number.

Note: I referred to the ECMAScript 5 spec but you can find something equivalent in the newer versions.