# How to convert string value in an object to a number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, numbers

I have an object where the number values for the `user_id` are strings but I want to change these to return as numbers, how can I do this?

```
const users =
[
 { user_id: '1', name: 'Jack'},
 { user_id: '2', name: 'Emma'},
 { user_id: '3', name: 'David'}
]

// I want the output to look like this

const users =
[
 { user_id: 1, name: 'Jack'},
 { user_id: 2, name: 'Emma'},
 { user_id: 3, name: 'David'}
]
```

Comment: Maybe loop over the users somehow, e.g. using a `for` loop? What have you tried yet?

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over an array? How to access a property? How to assign to a property? How to convert a value to a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inplace

```
users.forEach(u=>u.user_id*=1)
```

```js
const users =
[
 { user_id: '1', name: 'Jack'},
 { user_id: '2', name: 'Emma'},
 { user_id: '3', name: 'David'}
]

users.forEach(u=>u.user_id*=1)

console.log(users);
```

Comment: I really like this. Using the `+` as an operator for type coercion is a great trick, but in this case it leads to a bit lengthier code rather than `*=1`, and since the OP didn't specify a functional approach, even though he's declaring with `const`, using `.forEach` to manipulate the original object is perfectly acceptable. Definitely adding to my toolbox. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `map`, and use the unary `+` operator to convert to numbers.

```js
const users = [{
    user_id: '1',
    name: 'Jack'
  },
  {
    user_id: '2',
    name: 'Emma'
  },
  {
    user_id: '3',
    name: 'David'
  }
];

const res = users.map(({ name, user_id }) => ({ name, user_id: +user_id }));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var users = [{
    user_id: '1',
    name: 'Jack'
  },
  {
    user_id: '2',
    name: 'Emma'
  },
  {
    user_id: '3',
    name: 'David'
  }
];

var res = users.map(function(user) { 
  return { name: user.name, user_id: +user.user_id };
});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
return users.map(user => ({...user, user_id: +user.user_id}))
```

Comment: Mind explaining to the OP the map function, spread operator, fat-arrow function and unary-plus?

Comment: @Kerndog73 mind write this comment and `-1` for each answer here?

Comment: Just for the record, I didn't actually downvote this answer

Answer (score 0):

May be like:-

```js
let users =
[
 { user_id: '1', name: 'Jack'},
 { user_id: '2', name: 'Emma'},
 { user_id: '3', name: 'David'}
];


users = users.map(a =>  {
  a.user_id = +a.user_id;
  return a;
});
console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

*I know this question already has an answer, but I wanted to offer an alternative solution that you may find beneficial and I'll explain why.*

### Answer:

Instead of utilizing a typical `transform` on the `users` array, you can apply a `Proxy` to each object and utilize the `get` handler to test if a property's value is able to be coerced [to a `number` by using the `+` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867329/why-does-implicit-coercion-for-addition-always-produce-a-string). This is done using a [**short-circuit** evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation), which returns the first true expression. If a property's value cannot be turned into a `number`, it will return the original value with no coercion( in this case, a `string` ).

```
users = users.map(_ => 
  new Proxy(_, {get: (target, property) => +target[property] || target[property]}))
```

---

### Why is this useful?

Code will *always* rely on your use-case. In your question you asked how to convert `user_id` to a `number` within your `users` object. If this is a one-off situation where you only need this specific property to be coerced to a numeric value, applying a proxy to your objects would not be recommended.

**however**

If you find yourself in a situation where you have a number of property values that you would like converted to `number` types if possible, you may consider using the above technique so that you don't have to pinpoint and update each property name within a separate conversion function.

**Note:** Since we are using a `map` method to bundle our original objects with a `Proxy` handler,you would either need to use a different declarative (`var` or `let`), or use `Array.from` in your original `users` declaration:

```
const users = Array.from(
[
 { user_id: '1', name: 'Jack'},
 { user_id: '2', name: 'Emma'},
 { user_id: '3', name: 'David'}
], _ => new Proxy(_, {get: (target, property) => +target[property] || target[property]}));
```

---

### Code Example:

```js
let users = 
[{
    user_id: '1',
    name: 'Jack'
  },
  {
    user_id: '2',
    name: 'Emma'
  },
  {
    user_id: '3',
    name: 'David'
  }
];

users = users.map(_ => new Proxy(_, { get: (target, property) => +target[property] || target[property]}))

users.forEach(({user_id, name}) => (console.log("user id: " + user_id + " is type: " + typeof user_id), console.log("name: " + name + " is type: " + typeof name)));
```